# Python Regex match phone Number

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that trying to match these phone number format. I'm super close except 1 scenario:

Regex: `^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$`

Phone number format are trying to match:

- (123) 456-7890
- (123) 4567890
- 123-456-7890
- 123-4567890
- 1234567890
- 1234567890

I also want to match this.... there is leading spaces before and after the area code:

[empty spaces] (123) [emtpy spaces] 456-7890

Answer (score 3):

```
^\s*\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]*(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})$
```

This should do it.

The `*` character means 0 or more of preceding.

[Regexr](http://regexr.com/4l624) is probably the best tool I know to figure out how to change regex patterns.

Comment: It still doesn't match the empty spaces before and after the area code. I just tested on regex101.com

Comment: That's because you changed the requirement after I posted it, but give me a second I'll fix it.

Comment: @user11666514 Now it does.

Comment: Is there not a simpler way? `^ ?\(?(\d{3})\)?([-\. ]+)?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$` . Comparison: `^(\s+)`/ `^ ?`

Comment: @BlackThunder that wouldn't cover multiple spaces or non-standard space characters but if you added the `( +)?` it would I suppose.

Comment: Great @user11666514 , click the check mark if it answered your question. Thanks!

Comment: `(\s+)?` is far simpler to write as `\s*` since it is probably not needed to capture spaces for later processing... Also you do not need to escape characters in characters classes, so `[-\. ]+` is in fact `[-. ]+`